# cshtml onclick button event and pass a value

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, umbraco

I have been searching for a solution to this I have a button function

html

```
<button class="snipcart-add-item btn c8-bg c5-text" onclick="AddProduct(item.Id)">

    @umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("USN Shop Add to Basket Listing")
</button>
```

item.id has got a value as it works in an original code that I are trying to bypass

java script is

```
function AddProduct(ptr) {
    $('select').on('click', function () {
        s.ajac({
            url: '/CartSurface/ProductAddToCart',
            data: "{'productId':ptr}",
        }).done(function () {
            alert('Added');
        });
    });
    console.log("Button Pressed")
}
```

and I get the following error when the button is pressed in the console.log

Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

controller

```
public static void ProductAddToCart(int productId)
{
  ......
}
```

I think I have missed something stupidly simple but I cant see it

Following Owns comments

Thanks Own have changed code to

```
function AddProduct(value) {
        $('select').on("click", function () {
            s.ajac({
                url: '/IBDCartSurface/ProductAddToCart',
                data: "{'productId': value}",
            }).done(function () {
                alert('Added');
            });
        });
        console.log(value);
        console.log("Button Pressed");
    }

<button class="snipcart-add-item btn c8-bg c5-text" onclick="AddProduct(value)" value="@item.Id">
```

I get the value in the console and the "Button Pressed" message but my break point dont get triggered and the alert dosnt get triggered.

Can I ask what is the differance between s.ajac and $.ajax other than the latter cant find the url.

Note I have changed the Controller name in the controller as well

Comment: You have to define 'item' before using it in onclick event. On other side, I don't now which Umbraco version you are using but I recommend you to use `Umbraco.Field("#USN Shop Add to Basket Listing")` to get your dictionary item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a different way to do it. I dont entirely understand all of it but I get the gist of it.

Wrap the button in the controller call where the id is the name of the controller function. Means not having to translate from one code type to another etc.

values are retrieved from the 2 input tags

csHtml

```
using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<IBDCartSurfaceController>("SiteWideAddToBasket", null, new { @class = "form", role = "form" }))
{
  <input type="hidden" id="productPageId" name="productPageId" value="@item.Id" />
  <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" value="@item.ProductCurrentPrice" />
  <button class="snipcart-add-item btn c8-bg c5-text" id="addToBasket" type="submit">
    @umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("USN Shop Add to Basket Listing")
  </button>
}
```

Then the Controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SiteWideAddToBasket(int productPageId, decimal productPrice)
{
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Your button element is passing the item ID as an argument for AddProduct. The error is telling you that the variable `item` either doesn't exist or is outside of the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS to something like:

```
document.on("click", "#buttonId", function(){
    data = $(this).attr("data-id");
    s.ajac({
        url: '/CartSurface/ProductAddToCart',
        data: "{'productId': data}",
    }).done(function () {
        alert('Added');
    });
}
```

Then change your html to

```
<button class="snipcart-add-item btn c8-bg c5-text" id="buttonId" data-id="item.id">
    @umbraco.library.GetDictionaryItem("USN Shop Add to Basket Listing")
</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this was tagged with umbraco.  disregard as i'm unfamiliar with how that might changes things.